# 1.39 Rally API Version source for Java Script

Tags: rally

I'm interested in using the 1.39 version of Rally API with JavaScript. But i'm not finding the source for it.

It should be something like this:

```
<script src="/apps/1.39/sdk.js"></script>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most current version of Rally's AppSDK 1.x is version 1.33. If you need to use 1.33 with a more current version of the Webservices API, you can do so as follows:

`<script type="text/javascript" src="/apps/1.33/sdk.js?apiVersion=1.39"></script>`

Rally's not planning further development on AppSDK version 1. For new apps, I'd recommend using AppSDK2. You can find good information on getting started with AppSDK2 from the following resources:

- [Getting Started](https://developer.help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0rc1/doc/#!/guide/getting_started)
- [Developing Apps Externally](https://developer.help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0rc1/doc/#!/guide/developing_externally)
- [Data Stores](https://developer.help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0rc1/doc/#!/guide/data_stores)
- [Data Visualization](https://developer.help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0rc1/doc/#!/guide/data_visualization)