# Rally Webservice v2.0 via SDK 1.32?

Tags: web-services, sdk, rally

My question is concerning the Rally javascript SDK 1.32.

My line of thinking is this: SDK 1.32 seems to only return objects with APIMajorVersion 1 and MinorVersion 32, yet there exist versions from 1.33 to 1.43 as well (though they are all now deprecated as well). It makes sense to me that since SDK 2.0 must return objects from version 2.0, that there should be a way to specify what webservice version to return objects from.

My question is this: am I right that there is a way to obtain Rally objects from webservice v2.0 from SDK 1.32? If so, how would I do that?

I'm not just asking this out of laziness-- I am on the tail-end of an internship and would not necessarily have time to learn the new SDK and reimplement all that I have done on SDK 1.32.

Thanks for any responses!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer:

[1.39 Rally API Version source for Java Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17620158/1-39-rally-api-version-source-for-java-script)

shows how to utilize AppSDK 1.x using different versions of WSAPI.

However, AppSDK 1.x utilizes the adhoc.js Webservices endpoint for querying. This endpoint has been deprecated in Webservices 2.0. As a result, AppSDK 1.x will not work against Rally Webservices 2.0.

I'd recommend using AppSDK 2rc1, which is built on Webservices 2.0.